# Verilog Code for this (simple) Logic Gate?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, logic-gates

[image: The Logic Gate]

Here's as far as I've gotten with this:

```
module Lab2pl(input x3, x2, x1, x0, output f, g, h);
  wire z3, z2, z1, z0, notx2, notx1;

  and
  a0(x0, x2, z0),
  a1(x1, x3, z1),
  a2(z2, z3, h, f);

  not
  n0(x2, notx2),
  n1(x1, notx1);


  or
  o0(z0, z1, g, f),
  o1(notx2, x0, z2),
  o2(notx1, x3, z3),
  o3(f);
Endmodule
```

It really doesn't make any sense to me how the wires going from o0/a2 into o3 aren't labeled. I can't find any helpful tutorials or resources and this is due tonight. Any help would be HUGELY appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> It really doesn't make any sense to me how the wires going from o0/a2 into o3 aren't labeled.

They *are* labelled -- they're `g` and `h`.

Here's a redrawn version of that part of the schematic which might make it clearer what is intended:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT2PFMm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Fix the instantiations of `o0`, `a2`, and `o3` such that there are two inputs and one output for each one. Besides that, what you've got looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your port order on the Verilog primitives is incorrect.

The first port for all Verilog primitives is an output. Multiple inputs are allowed for `and`, `nand`, `nor`, `or`, `xor`, `xnor`. Multiple outputs is supported from `buf` and `not` with the last port treated a the input.

The wire form o0 to o3 is defined: `g`.
The wire form a2 to o3 is also defined: `h`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to use `assign` statements? This would yield a more concise, C language-like representation of your logic.

Then again, if the point of the exercise is to use the predefined functions in Verilog (more here: http://verilog.renerta.com/source/vrg00003.htm) then you wouldn't use `assign`.

That said, how to check this then?

All the gates are 2-in 1-out with a variable list (in,in,out) and two inverters (in, out). Check the gate signal lists carefully. You will notice something off about several of them.

And, yes, the inputs to gate `o3` do have labels. You created them in your wire list, and assigned them to a signal level with the outputs from gates `o0` and `a2`.

Comment: I get the sense that this exercise is intended to demonstrate to the student how structural Verilog can get clunky when used this way. :)